# Scale from start rect to final position

Tags: android, objectanimator

I'm trying to scale view from start rectangle (e.g. defined by another view) to it's final position.

I tried to use the following code to setup animations which looks straight forward:

```
float scaleX = 0f;
float scaleY = 0f;
Rect startRect = new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100); // taken from real view position with getLocationOnScreen
final Collection<Animator> animators = new ArrayList<>();

if (animatedView.getMeasuredHeight() != 0) {
    scaleX = (float)startRect.width() / animatedView.getMeasuredWidth();
}

if (animatedView.getMeasuredHeight() != 0) {
    scaleY = (float)startRect.height() / animatedView.getMeasuredHeight();
}

animatedView.getLocationInWindow(location);
animatedView.setPivotX(startRect.left);
animatedView.setPivotY(startRect.top);
animatedView.setScaleX(scaleX);
animatedView.setScaleY(scaleY);

animators.add(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animatedView, View.SCALE_X, 1.0f).setDuration(1000));
animators.add(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animatedView, View.SCALE_Y, 1.0f).setDuration(1000));
```

The `animatedView` is child of `RelativeLayout` (layout parameters set to below some title view of layout) and measured width and height and location are valid values at the moment of animation setup.

Depending on `startRect` I observe different animations - sometimes animated view get displayed below or above `startRect`.

Seems RectEvaluator is one of possible solutions, but it's available only from API 18.

What is the proper way to animate view from start rectangle position to final (not modified one)?

Comment: use `android.animation.RectEvaluator`

Comment: @pskink looks promising. Should I apply result rect on every step using translation and scale properties?

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/jaXTjGjA

Comment: @pskink thanks! Is there a way to make view match that rect?

Comment: yes,  by calling setTranslateX/Y and serScaleX/Y

Comment: @pskink it seems to work, however, it's only from API 18. Modified the question accordingly.

Comment: What API do you need? Why won't copying the code of `RectEvaluator` work for you?

Comment: yes, azizbekian is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments on the question, it's possible to copy [RectEvaluator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/RectEvaluator.html) code from Android source, and then apply the following logic:

```
RectViewAnimator mRectAnimator;

/**
 * Creates animator which can be played. From some start position
 * to final (real position).
 * From final position to start position can be achieved using reverse interpolation.
 */
private Collection<Animator> createMoveAnimators(View targetView, Rect startRect) {
    final Collection<Animator> animators = new ArrayList<>();
    final int[] location = new int[2];

    targetView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    final Rect finalRect = new Rect(location[0], location[1],
            location[0] + targetView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            location[1] + targetView.getMeasuredHeight());

    // Must keep this reference during animations, since Animator keeps only WeakReference to it's targets.
    mRectAnimator = appendRectEvaluatorAnimation(animators, targetView, 500, startRect, finalRect);

    return animators;
}

private RectViewAnimator appendRectEvaluatorAnimation(final Collection<Animator> animators, final View view, final int duration,
                                                      final Rect startRect, final Rect finalRect) {
    final float scaleX = (float) startRect.width() / finalRect.width();
    final float scaleY = (float) startRect.height() / finalRect.height();

    view.setTranslationY(startRect.top - (finalRect.top + (1 - scaleY) * finalRect.height() / 2));
    view.setTranslationX(startRect.left - (finalRect.left + (1 - scaleX) * finalRect.width() / 2));
    view.setScaleX(scaleX);
    view.setScaleY(scaleY);

    final RectViewAnimator rectViewAnimator = new RectViewAnimator(view, finalRect);
    final Animator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(rectViewAnimator, RectViewAnimator.RECT,
            new RectEvaluator(), startRect, finalRect);

    animators.add(animator);
    return rectViewAnimator;
}

private static class RectViewAnimator {
    static final String RECT = "rect";

    private final View target;
    private final Rect finalRect;

    RectViewAnimator(final View target, final Rect finalRect) {
        this.target = target;
        this.finalRect = finalRect;
    }

    @Keep
    public void setRect(final Rect r) {
        final float scaleX = (float)r.width() / finalRect.width();
        final float scaleY = (float)r.height() / finalRect.height();

        target.setScaleX(scaleX);
        target.setScaleY(scaleY);
        target.setTranslationX(r.left - (finalRect.left + (1 - scaleX) * finalRect.width() / 2));
        target.setTranslationY(r.top - (finalRect.top + (1 - scaleY) * finalRect.height() / 2));
    }
}
```